# cannot run cxf in osgi xmlschema bundle missing (but it is installed)

Tags: osgi, cxf

I am trying to run a cxf bundle in karaf. It says that the package org.apache.ws.commons.schema is missing but the appropiate bundle is already installed (servicemix bundle)

I dont know why the dependency is not solved if the bundle 785 (xmlschema) is activated. Do I need to include something else or do I have some sort of configuration problem?

```
OSGi>features:install idb
Refreshing bundles org.springframework.jms (104)
Error executing command: Could not start bundle 
mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle-minimal/2.2.9 in feature(s)
 cxf-bundle-minimal-2.6.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle
 org.apache.cxf.bundle-minimal [832]: Unable to resolve 832.0:
 missing requirement [832.0] package;
 (&(package=org.apache.ws.commons.schema)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))

OSGi>osgi:info 785

Apache ServiceMix Bundles: xmlschema-1.4.3 (785)
------------------------------------------------
OSGi>osgi:headers 785

Apache ServiceMix Bundles: xmlschema-1.4.3 (785)
------------------------------------------------
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Bnd-LastModified = 1237594240914
Tool = Bnd-0.0.255
Built-By = gnodet
Build-Jdk = 1.5.0_16
Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin

Bundle-Vendor = The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-Name = Apache ServiceMix Bundles: xmlschema-1.4.3
Bundle-DocURL = http://www.apache.org/
Bundle-Description = This bundle simply wraps xmlschema-1.4.3.jar.
Bundle-SymbolicName = org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlschema
Bundle-Version = 1.4.3.1
Bundle-License = http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2

Import-Package = 
javax.xml.namespace,
javax.xml.parsers,
javax.xml.transform,
javax.xml.transform.dom,
javax.xml.transform.sax,
javax.xml.transform.stream,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema;version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.constants;version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.extensions;version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver;version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils;version=1.4.3,
org.w3c.dom,
org.xml.sax
Export-Package = 
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver;uses:=org.xml.sax;version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils;
    uses:="org.apache.ws.commons.schema,
        javax.xml.namespace,
        org.w3c.dom";
    version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema;
    uses:="org.xml.sax,
        javax.xml.namespace,
        org.w3c.dom,
        javax.xml.transform,
        org.apache.ws.commons.schema.extensions,
        javax.xml.transform.dom,
        javax.xml.transform.sax,
        org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver,
        org.apache.ws.commons.schema.utils,
        javax.xml.parsers,
        org.apache.ws.commons.schema.constants,
        javax.xml.transform.stream";
    version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.constants;
    uses:=javax.xml.namespace;
    version=1.4.3,
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.extensions;
    uses:="org.apache.ws.commons.schema,
        javax.xml.namespace,
        org.w3c.dom";
    version=1.4.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CXF version you use seems to be quite old. Can you test this with the most recent CXF version? Btw. What Karaf version are you using?

Comment: I switched to the singlebundle release version 1.3.1 to solve the issue. I would prefer to keep the dependencies separated, but it will have to do for the moment.

Comment: I still cant make it run, but I have a different error, hehe. I'll try to figure it out

Comment: The newest release of CXF (2.6.x) now has separate bundles which make CXF quite modular in OSGi. As the feature is quite fresh you still may encounter some small problems with the separate bundles. The easiest way to use CXF is to use Karaf 2.2.7 and just do "features:chooseurl cxf 2.6.0" and "features:install cxf". I have a full tutorial about CXF in Karaf here: http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/EoBk

Comment: thanks. I actually found that tutorial before but I was using the dosgi thing that seemed easier. and I am using blueprints now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the state of bundle 785 (xmlschema-1.4.3) ?
If the state is resolved or active, it is ok; if it is only "installed", then there is a problem with it and the packages it exports are *not* available in the system.

Second, check who provides the packages imported by bundle 785. (org.w3c.dom etc)
You could have the following situation: 
If bundle idb imports e.g. org.w3c.dom from one source, and xmlschema-1.4.3 imports them from another (e.g. different versions are available at the same time, or both the framework itself and some additional bundle provide it) then the framework won't resolve the idb bundle with the package from xmlschema-1.4.3, because this would lead to a ClassCastException later on.

Comment: the state is active. I will check your suggestion